# Child static constructor not called when base member accessed

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class defined as:

```
public class DatabaseEntity<T> where T : DatabaseEntity<T> {
    public static string Query { get; protected set; }
    public static IList<T> Load() {
        return Database.Get(Query);
    }
}

public class Node : DatabaseEntity<Node> {
    static Node() {
        Node.Query = @"SELECT Id FROM Node";
    }
}
```

When I run `Node.Load()` from a codebehind (`Window.xaml.cs`) the Node's static constructor never fires; or at least doesn't hit a breakpoint and does not set Node.Query to anything other than null.

Is there any reason why this might occur?

**Solution**

Check out the answers below for a few solutions. For my case, I decided to simply make the `Query` variable public, and set all instances of `Query` in one place. (Not ideal, but it works.)

Comment: Is it being de-serialized via a DataContractSerializer ? As I recall DCS does not fire constructors.

Comment: Why not simply make query `private const string Query = [query];`?

Comment: It is not. However, `Load()` is actually an inherited static function. Would that make a difference?

Comment: @CharlesW Inherited static? There's no such thing, there's only hiding, in which case it's not called.

Comment: I've edited the post to reflect the 'inheritance'.

Comment: With this code you will have problems: There is only one query property for all entity types and thus all entity will share the same query (the last one which has been loaded)....

Comment: @RicoSuter If `T` is different, then Query will be different. `DatabaseEntity<Node>.Query != DatabaseEntity<SubNode>.Query`

Comment: Ok yes, you are right...

Comment: However using static methods is bad design (singleton) and this code cannot be tested with mocks/stubs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem lies in your assumptions about when a static constructor is called.  The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc%28VS.80%29.aspx), which isn't the clearest, states that

> It is called automatically before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced.

You may assume that if you call

```
Node.Load();
```

that you are calling a static method on the `Node` class, but in fact you're calling it on the base class, as that is where it is implemented.

So, to fix this, you have two choices.  First, you can trigger the static constructor explicitly by creating a new instance of the Node class prior to calling `Load()`

```
var foo = new Node(); // static ctor triggered
Node.Load();
```

or create a protected virtual member that the base class can call in order to get the query value (can't use abstract here, unfortunately)

```
public class DatabaseEntity<T> where T : Derp {
    protected abstract string Query { get; }
    public static IList<T> Load() {        
        return Database.Get(new DatabaseEntity<T>().Query);
    }
}
```

Both of which are hacky.  Better to dispense with the statics altogether and go with instance methods.  Statics should be used sparingly, as they result in tight coupling and other design headaches such as this.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, static constructors will not be called till the members of the class is first accessed or first instance is created.

In your case you're accessing `DatabaseEntity<T>.Load`, so static constructor of `DatabaseEntity<T>` will be called not its derived class ones.

Even though you call `Node.Load` it is mapped to `DatabaseEntity<Node>` at compile time. So technically you're not accessing `Node` class at all.

Comment: This is correct, you can demonstrate this behavior by creating an instance of the node class before calling Node.Load() and it should work. If no instance is made before the call it will not.

Comment: This is a great explanation. Can you offer any hints or advice on how to solve this problem? (Besides the obvious, `Node n = new Node();`)

Comment: @CharlesW I suspect this is a design problem. Without knowing more about what you're trying to achieve I can't help with this sorry. Obvious workaround will be to add `Node.Load` method with new modifier which simply calls base class implementation, but. I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also call class constructors directly using `System.Runtime.CompilerServices` and the `RuntimeHelpers` type by doing something as follows:
`RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(type.TypeHandle);`

So for example you could use reflection to loop over all types in an inheritance chain and call each of the static constructors.